# How do I have beautiful soup read in the html fully? Possibly selenium issue?

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tags

I am trying to have some practice with beautiful soup, web scraping and python but I am struggling with getting this data from certain tags. I am trying to go through multiple pages of data on cars.com.

So when I read in the html, and the tags I need are

```
<cars-shop-srp-pagination>
</cars-shop-srp-pagination>
```

because the page number is in between them and in order for me to loop through the website pages, I need to know the max pages

```
from bs4
import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.cars.com/for-sale/searchresults.action/?dealerType=all&mkId=20089&page=1&perPage=20&prMx=25000&rd=99999&searchSource=GN_REFINEMENT&sort=relevance&stkTypId=28881&zc=21042'

#
source = requests.get('https://www.cars.com/for-sale/searchresults.action/?dealerType=all&mdId=58767&mkId=20089&page=1&perPage=20&prMx=25000&rd=99999&searchSource=GN_REFINEMENT&sort=relevance&zc=21042').text
source = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())
link = soup.find(word_ = "cars-shop-srp-pagination")# linkNext = link.find('a')
print(link)
```

When I go through the output, the only thing I see for the "cars-shop-srp-pagination: is

```
 <cars-shop-srp-pagination>
 </cars-shop-srp-pagination>
```

when I need to see:

All of the code inside of them, specifically I want to get to:

```
*"<li ng-if="showLast"> <a class="js-last-page" ng-click="goToPage($event, numberOfPages)">50</a> </li>"*
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that BeautifulSoup only parses through HTML/XML code that you give it.  If the page number isn't in your captured HTML code in your first place, then that's a problem with being able to capture the code properly, not with BeautifulSoup.  Unfortunately, I think that this data is dynamically generated.

I found a work-around, though.  Notice that at the top of the search results, the page says "(*some number of cars*) matches near you". For example:

```
<div class="matchcount">
   <span class="filter-count">1,711</span>
   <span class="filter-text"> matches near you</span>
```

You could capture this number, then divide by the number of results per page being displayed.  In fact, this latter number can be passed into the URL.  Note that you have to round up to the nearest integer, to catch the search results that show up on the final page.  Also, any commas in numbers over 999 have to be removed from the string before you can `int` it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import math

perpage = 100
url = 'https://www.cars.com/for-sale/searchresults.action/'
url += '?dealerType=all&mdId=58767&mkId=20089&page=1&perPage=%d' % perpage
url += '&prMx=25000&searchSource=PAGINATION&sort=relevance&zc=21042'

response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
source = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

count_tag = soup.find('span', {'class' : 'filter-count'})
count = int(count_tag.text.replace(',',''))
pages = int(math.ceil(1.0* count / perpage))
print(pages)
```

One catch to this however is that if the search isn't refined enough, the website will say something like "Over 30 thousand matches", which is not an integer.

Also, I was getting a 503 response from `requests.get()`, so I switched to using `urllib2` to get the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

All that info (number of results, number of pages, results per page) is stored in a javascript dictionary within the returned content. You can simply regex out the object and parse with json. Note that the url is a query string and you can alter the results per page count in it. So, after doing an initial request to determine how many results there are, you can perform calcs to make any other changes. Note that you may also be able to use json through out and not BeautifulSoup. Though I think there would be a limit (perhaps the 20) with grabbing as shown below from each page so probably better to go with the 100 results per page and make initial request, regex out info and if more than 100 results then loop, altering url, to collect rest of results.

I don't think, regardless of the number of pages indicated/calculated, that you can actually go beyond page 50.

```
import requests
import re
import json

p = re.compile(r'digitalData = (.*?);')
r = requests.get('https://www.cars.com/for-sale/searchresults.action/?dealerType=all&mkId=20089&page=1&perPage=20&prMx=25000&rd=99999&searchSource=GN_REFINEMENT&sort=relevance&stkTypId=28881&zc=21042')
data = json.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])
num_results_returned = data['page']['search']['numResultsReturned']
total_num_pages = data['page']['search']['totalNumPages']
num_results_on_page =  data['page']['search']['numResultsOnPage']
```